# Angular 2 AoT Heep Errors

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-directives, angular2-services

AoT compilation resulting in " JavaScript heap out of memory" error

I am trying to compile my project by following the AoT guide available on angular.io

Below is my typesccript configuration file for aot

`{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "../content/app/"
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "genDir": "aot",
    "skipMetadataEmit": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}`

I am compiling using below command:

`D:\MyProject\node_modules\.bin>ngc -p ../../app/tsconfig-aot.json`

It takes times in compilation and ends up with below errors:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

  215225 ms: Mark-sweep 1327.9 (1434.3) -> 1316.1 (1434.3) MB, 1233.5 / 0.0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
  216639 ms: Mark-sweep 1316.1 (1434.3) -> 1316.1 (1434.3) MB, 1413.5 / 0.0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
  217985 ms: Mark-sweep 1316.1 (1434.3) -> 1320.4 (1403.3) MB, 1346.7 / 0.0 ms [last resort gc].
  219337 ms: Mark-sweep 1320.4 (1403.3) -> 1324.6 (1403.3) MB, 1351.5 / 0.0 ms [last resort gc].


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 00000023CEBCFB61 <JS Object>
    1: copyProperties [D:\MyProject\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:1462] [pc=000001870A3EC95C] (this=000000AAE12C6A41 <an Object with map 00000279F6259FA1>,source=000002E70921E389 <an Object with map 00000279F62D8539>,target=000002ED3C5C7691 <an Object with map 000000D6F40CD1C9>)
    2: objectTypeRelatedTo [D:\MyProject\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

D:\MyProject\node_modules\.bin>
```

The project I am trying to compile has 467 files.

Answer (score 1):

If you still have this issue on windows after trying the accepted answer you can use the following workaround (@angular/compiler-cli 2.2.1):

```
node --max-old-space-size=8192 node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/main.js -p tsconfig-aot.json
```

This might not work with future updates as all the above does is point to the actual js file if you interpret ./node_modules/.bin/ngc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I was FINALLY able to compile my project with ngc (after a month of looking everywhere and failing each time)

This doesn't work on windows for some reason, but it worked on a mac machine

first compile with main.ts in JIT mode

`./node_modules/.bin/ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json`

then change main.ts to AoT mode and run

`node --max-old-space-size=8192 ./node_modules/.bin/ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json`

I literally had to go as far as 8192 (8GB) to not run out of memory (it goes as far as 5-6GB for my project)

then build the rollup bundle

`node --max-old-space-size=8192 node_modules/.bin/rollup -c rollup.js`

if everything went well, now you should have a production bundle.

**A note on Lazy loading** - I'm not using lazy loading as if I do, ngc just ignores all the lazy loaded modules and does not generate AoT files for them.
I believe lazy loading is supposed to be used only if you're not going to generate a production build and is going to use a module loader like SystemJS or Webpack to load your project

My machine is

[image: screen shot 2016-11-03 at 10 29 06 am]

Comment: Just for the sake to clarification, when you say "ngc just ignores all the lazy loaded modules and does not generate AoT files for them"  are you referring to ngfactory files? that are generated when we run ngc for the first time?

Comment: Yes the ngfactory files.

Comment: for me ngc isn't generating the ngfactory files for modules that are lazy loaded. If a module is lazy loaded, it shouldn't be imported into app.module. So because of that, ngc generates the ngfactory files for only those modules that are directly imported into app.module file and ignores the lazy loaded ones

Answer (score 0):

`node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng [command]`

e.g `node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve`

worked for me on my windows machine