# Javascript out of memory during angular prod build

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, webpack

I am getting **following error** while doing a prod build for my angular 4 project in windows 10:

```
92% chunk asset optimization
<--- Last few GCs --->

[2608:000002518B1007B0]   578653 ms: Mark-sweep 1400.7 (1534.2) -> 1400.7 (1502.2) MB, 1409.9 / 0.0 ms  last resort
[2608:000002518B1007B0]   579952 ms: Mark-sweep 1400.7 (1502.2) -> 1400.7 (1501.2) MB, 1298.6 / 0.0 ms  last resort


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0000003DF7DA66A1 <JS Object>
    1: DoJoin(aka DoJoin) [native array.js:~97] [pc=0000032E01B053FC](this=000001F775C02311 <undefined>,q=0000010002582251 <JS Array[4]>,r=4,F=000001F775C023B1 <true>,B=000001F775C02471 <String[0]: >,A=000001F775C02421 <false>)
    2: Join(aka Join) [native array.js:~122] [pc=0000032E01E5AD22](this=000001F775C02311 <undefined>,q=0000010002582251 <JS Array[4]>,r=4,B=000001F775C02471 <String[0]...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

**What I Tried:**
Edited webpack.cmd as below (as suggested in one of the SO posts), but this didn't helped:

```
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
    "%~dp0\node.exe" --max_old_space_size=8048 
    "%~dp0\..\webpack\bin\webpack.js" %*
    ) ELSE (
    @SETLOCAL
    @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
    node --max_old_space_size=8048
    node  "%~dp0\..\webpack\bin\webpack.js" %*
)
```

**Extra Info**

```
@angular/cli: 1.0.0
node: 7.9.0
os: win32 x64
@angular/animations: 4.1.3
@angular/common: 4.1.3
@angular/compiler: 4.1.3
@angular/core: 4.1.3
@angular/forms: 4.1.3
@angular/http: 4.1.3
@angular/platform-browser: 4.1.3
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.1.3
@angular/router: 4.1.3
@angular/cli: 1.0.0
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.1.3
```

In all the github and SO pages for this issue, it is suggested to allocate more memory to node, I did that too, but didn't worked out.
I badly need to do a prod build, please advice how can I overcome this issue

Comment: Your version of adding more memory is not the same as the one posted in the answer. The answer is setting the flag on single node execution for webpack. You version has 2 node execution, first one plain node with increase heap flag but doing nothing and second one running webpack without the memory increase.

Comment: I noticed this only after Marcelo pointed it out. So I made the changes, but still getting the same error

Comment: Try changing `ng.cmd` instead of `webpack.cmd`

Comment: tried that too... didn't worked

Comment: I tried with Ubuntu also, getting same error there also...

Comment: Found one solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39945756/angular-2-aot-heep-errors

but as mentioned here, this works only for Mac and not for windows. Am still looking for a workaround/solution for this issue on windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've changed `max_old_space_size` in `ng.cmd` file inside `%AppData%\npm` (Windows) and it did the trick.

I no longer face any issue while launching `ng build --prod --env=prod --base-href .`

Comment: Approve your own answer so people know it is the solution! :-)

Comment: This is a fantastic answer that ACTUALLY solved this ongoing problem for us. Also worked for Karma and Webpack on Windows as well (same folder karma.cmd, webpack.cmd). Well done.

Answer (score 0):

To actually increase the memory size you need to use the flag `max_old_space_size` with the file call. Change your code to:

```
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
     "%~dp0\node.exe" --max_old_space_size=8048 
     "%~dp0\..\webpack\bin\webpack.js" %*
     ) ELSE (
     @SETLOCAL
    @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
  node --max_old_space_size=8048 "%~dp0\..\webpack\bin\webpack.js" %*
)
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: I made the changes you suggested @Marcelo, but I am still getting the same error

Comment: Do I need to make any chngs to webpack file also? It's content are as follows:

#!/bin/sh
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")

case `uname` in
    *CYGWIN*) basedir=`cygpath -w "$basedir"`;;
esac

if [ -x "$basedir/node" ]; then
  "$basedir/node"  "$basedir/../webpack/bin/webpack.js" "$@"
  ret=$?
else 
  node  "$basedir/../webpack/bin/webpack.js" "$@"
  ret=$?
fi
exit $ret

Comment: Put only in the call that is failing. How much RAM your machine has?

Comment: My machine have 12GB RAM

Comment: I am using this command to do prod build: 

ng build --prod --env=prod --base-href .

does this information help in any way?